# Validation warning in Data Flow Task in the SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, data-warehouse

I am trying to load data into my DimEmployee table using the Data Flow Task. However, I noticed when I run the SSIS, the DimEmployee filled with 4 records out of 9 and also the EmpKey starts counting from -1 then generates random numbers after that! Also I have  a warning associated when running the package:

> Warning   1   Validation warning. Data Flow Task:
>   {DC10B0CA-A6DE-4036-98A6-496811C09D4A}: Truncation may occur due to
>   inserting data from data flow column "TitleOfCourtesy" with a length
>   of 25 to database column "Title" with a length of 8. 
>     DimEmployee.dtsx    0   0

I created a procedure in my SSMS which supposes to fill the nulls in the columns by 'UNKNOWN'

```
USE [NorthWindDW]
GO


SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_New_Employee] 

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF NOT EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT * FROM [dbo].DimEmployee
        WHERE EmpKey = -1
    )

    BEGIN
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[DimEmployee] ON 
    INSERT [dbo].[DimEmployee] (EmpKey, EmpId,Title, EmpFirstName, EmpLastName, HireDate,Country, StoreCode, Telephone,JobTitle) VALUES
    (-1,-1,'UNKNOWN','UNKNOWN','UNKNOWN','1900-01-01', 'UNKNOWN','UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN','UNKNOWN');
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[DimEmployee] OFF
    END
END

GO
```

This is my DimEmployee Table

```
Create Table [dbo].[DimEmployee]
(EmpKey        INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
EmpId          INT NOT NULL,
EmpFirstName   NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
EmpLastName    NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Title          NVARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
HireDate       DATE        NOT NULL,
Country        NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
StoreCity      NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Telephone      NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
JobTitle       NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);
Go
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your warning looks to stem from your output column(s) database mapping.  The 'TitleOfCourtesy' output column datatype/length needs to match whichever column in DimEmployee it is mapped to.

As far as the 4 records go, I'd see what the data is in the 5th one, since that seems to be where the error is.  Whenever I have your issue, it's always a datatype mismatch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51463/discussion-between-dodi-and-mguerratorres).